# Trying to iterate through all messages in a discord channel with JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want to iterate through all messages in a channel in JDA, but im not sure how to do it. I have tried to get iterableHistory but it doesnt give me anything useful I think. Ive tried going through the docs but I cant find anything useful. Im trying to get a list or an array list if possible so that each message could be added to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Message> messageListRaw = (currentChannel.getHistoryFromBeginning(100).complete().getRetrievedHistory());
            ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>(messageListRaw);
            Collections.reverse(messageList);
            for (Message message :  messageList){
                //Use for 'message'
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

[net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.MessageChannel.getHistory()](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#getHistory())
[net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.MessageHistory.getRetrievedHistory()](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageHistory.html#getRetrievedHistory())

```java
MessageChannel channel;

// ...
// Initialize 'channel'
// ...

MessageHistory history = channel.getHistory();
final List<Message> retrievedHistory = new ArrayList<>(history.getRetrievedHistory());

Collections.reverse(retrievedHistory);

// oldest to newest
for (Message message : retrievedHistory) {
  // TODO use 'message'
}
```

Comment: gives error "foreach not applicable to type 'void'"

Comment: woops, I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As the two other ways shown here only go through a maximum of 100 messages, here is another way to really go through "all messages" - in this example a maximum of 1000 - using the [`getIterableHistory()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#getIterableHistory()) function.

```java
List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    messageList = channel.getIterableHistory().takeAsync(1000) // Collect 1000 messages
            .thenApply(list -> list.stream()
                // use .filter() here to cut down on the amount of messages
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Collections.reverse(messageList);

for (Message message : messageList) {
    // TODO use 'message'
}
```